# Javascript select nested class element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on changing some elements the slider on my website

my slider code looks like this:

```
<div class="cl1">
    <h1>Some heading</h1>
    <div class="sl_descr">Some description</div>
    <div class="sl_price">from only €00.00<br></div>
</div>

<div class="cl2">
    <h1>Some other heading</h1>
    <div class="sl_descr">Some other description</div>
    <div class="sl_price">from only €00.00<br></div>
</div>

<div class="cl3">
    <h1>yet some heading</h1>
    <div class="sl_descr">yet Some description</div>
    <div class="sl_price">from only €00.00<br></div>
</div>
```

I would like to change price when the currency changes. To do that I would like to use javascript with getElementsByClassName and then innerHTML. However my javascript doesn't work as wanted. Here it is

```
document.getElementsByClassName('cl1 sl_price').innerHTML="from only £00.00<br>";
```

any suggestions to how could I separately address "sl_price" class for every "cl" element? Cheers

Comment: When should this happen? You say 'when the currency changes,' but *when* does it change, how should the price change in response to the currency?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a collection (list) of elements
    (will therefore not have a `innerHTML` property)

You could try `document.querySelector(".cl1 .sl_price")` instead (takes a css selector and returns the **first match**)

read more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector

The end result would then be something like this;

```
document.querySelector('.cl1 .sl_price').innerHTML = "from only £00.00<br>";
```

---

**Note:** I am assuming you only wanted to match a single element. If not, you should look at @Bommox's answer and `querySelectorAll`.

Answer (score 13):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.cl1 .sl_price');
```

This will select all nested sl_price elements inside cl1. If you are looking to modify more cl's (i.e. cl1, cl2, cl3) just add a common class to all of them such as cl.

Answer (score 4):

You should do like this (if not using jQuery):

I have used "for" because I don't you if it may be more than one cl1 or sl_price whithin them.

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName("cl1");
for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
     var node = nodes[i].getElementsByClassName("sl_price");
     for(var j = 0; j < node.length; i++) {
          node.innerHTML="from only £00.00<br>";
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Jquery, the code is shorter than in native Javascript.

```
$('.cl1 .sl_price').html("from only £00.00<br>");
```

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/4zLbmrLq/

Answer (score 0):

Edit: this is wrong as it doesn't take into account that two class names are given.

I would suggest using JQuery for something like this, which will make it easier when you try to do something more complex. However the actual problem here is that `getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection` of elements, and setting `innerHTML` on it doesn't set it on its elements. The following code should work:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('cl1 sl_price');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].innerHTML = "from only £00.00<br>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe what you need to do is something like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('cl1').getElementsByClassName('sl_price')[0].innerHTML="from only £00.00<br>";
```

The way you're doing it right now will get elements that have both the classes cl1 and sl_price.  If you chain your methods, you'll be telling it to look for elements with cl1 as a class inside the document object, return an object with that subset, then look inside that subset for elements with the sl_price class.  You then have to specify an index because document.getElementsByClassName will return an array of elements matching your requirements.  That array will not have a property array.innerHTML, but the objects contained in its indexes will.