# How to get elements by class name only from one part of the document in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have two grids on page and both of them have "_status" class. I want to get elements only from the second grid.

If I use this:

```
var allVariants = document.getElementsByClassName("_status");
```

I will get elements from both grids. Both of my grids have different class "grid1" and "grid2". Is there any chance to get my elements using something like:

```
var allVariants = document.Find("grid2").getElementsByClassName("_status");
```

?

In my javascript method I want to add/remove some classes and add/remove some InnerText. When I click on radioButton on some row in my second grid, I send rowNumber and length (number of all rows) to this javascript method. Here is my javascript method:

```
function changeRowCheckedStatus(rowNumber, length) {
$('.radioButtonSelectColumn .radioButton :checked').attr('checked', true);
var allVariants = document.getElementsByClassName("_status");
allVariants[rowNumber - 1].innerText = "Changed";

for (i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
    if (i !== rowNumber) {
        var variant = "variant" + i;
        $('input[variant=' + variant + ']').removeAttr('checked');
        allVariants[i - 1].innerText = "NotChanged";
    }
}
```

}

So I want to add class "selected" and add InnerText = "Changed" to this row, and I want to remove class "selected" and add InnerText = "NotChanged" to all other rows. The problem is because var allVariants get all rows, and I want only rows from second grid.

Comment: `document.querySelector('.grid2').querySelectorAll('._status');`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript select nested class element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25487402/javascript-select-nested-class-element)

Comment: May be you can share sample HTML....

Answer (score 1):

You can use `querySelectorAll()`:

```
var allVariants = document.querySelectorAll("._status.grid2")[1];
```

Comment: But var allVariants = document.getElementsByClassName("_status"); is HTML Collection (which I need), and var allVariants = document.getElementsByClassName("_status")[1]; is not HTML Collection. Same problem with query selector.

Comment: You can use `.querySelectorAll` instead to get the collection

Comment: @Mamun Because the next line of code is: allVariants[rowNumber].innerText = "Changed";

Comment: @Nemanja, *allVariants* is a single element which may contain some more elements...... *rowNumber* is meaningless to me. `allVariants.innerText = "Changed";` should work........

Comment: @Mamun I added more code and explanation to my question. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [querySelectorAll](https://mdn.io/queryselectorall) to point to `grid2`:

```
var allVariants = document.querySelectorAll('.grid2 ._status');
```

Comment: OP says the grid *has* the `_status` class. Not that the `._status` class is in the `.grid`. Maybe consider changing your selector to `'.grid2._status'` or providing both variations

Comment: querySelectorAll takes css selector so ._status is needed

Comment: Yes, I know. But that's not the point of my comment. The suggested selector I provided is also a css selector. OP seems to say that the status class is part of the grid. So your current selector will select the status class inside the grid, not the status class which is part of the grid

Answer (score 0):

I can add id to both of my grids, and after that I can do this:

```
 var allVariants = document.getElementById("grid2").getElementsByClassName("_status");
```

Now it will be as HTML Collection.