# Can't Change Select Item in Table with Selenium Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm working with a really outdated site that's giving me issues. What I'm trying to do is select the "Judgement/Lien Search" tab as seen on: [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKPTe.png)

The issue is that there are no identifiers. No name, ID, etc.

```
<table border="0" bgcolor="#ededed" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
        <td width="33%" bgcolor="#ededed" nowrap=""><b><font size="+1"><u>Case Search</u></font></b></td>
        <td width="33%" bgcolor="#cccccc" nowrap=""><a href="javascript:submitJudgementSearch();" target="_self"><b><font size="+1">Judgment/Lien Search</font></b></a></td>
        <td width="33%" bgcolor="#cccccc" nowrap=""><a href="javascript:submitPropertySearch();" target="_self"><font size="+1"><b>Property/Lis Pendens Search</b></font></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

I've tried using xpath, css selector, and even just executing the script. I've been using ChroPath to get the correct info. When `<a href="javascript:submitJudgementSearch();" target="_self" xpath="1"><b><font size="+1">Judgment/Lien Search</font></b></a>` is selected ChroPath gives me these options:

Rel XPath: `//td[2]//a[1]`

Abs Xpath: `/html[1]/body[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[2]/a[1]`

CSS Selector: `table:nth-child(5) tbody:nth-child(1) tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1)`

None of which have actually worked when using driver.find options

When I try to just execute the javascript `driver.execute_script("javascript:submitJudgementSearch();")` I get error: "selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: submitJudgementSearch is not defined".

Any ideas on other ways to select it? Or am I looking at something wrong? This bump in the road really has me stumped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about using [Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) ?

Since your anchors seems to have unique href values this could work as a selector for the anchor itself. From there you could move up the dom to the parent if the `<td>` is indeed what you need.

```
$('a[href^="http://example.com/external/link"]').click(function() {});
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure where to start with this one.I played around with the code a bit and the one that gave me the least errors was: `driver.execute_script("$('a[href^=\"javascript:submitJudgementSearch();\"]');")`

Error: `selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: $ is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `document.querySelector` to get the job done potentially, refer to the snippet below. I was able to select that element using `document.querySelector`

```js
document.querySelector('td a b').style.color = "red";
```

```html
<table border="0" bgcolor="#ededed" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="33%" bgcolor="#ededed" nowrap=""><b><font size="+1"><u>Case Search</u></font></b></td>
      <td width="33%" bgcolor="#cccccc" nowrap=""><a href="javascript:submitJudgementSearch();" target="_self"><b><font size="+1">Judgment/Lien Search</font></b></a></td>
      <td width="33%" bgcolor="#cccccc" nowrap="">
        <a href="javascript:submitPropertySearch();" target="_self">
          <font size="+1"><b>Property/Lis Pendens Search</b></font>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Theres another example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25487402/javascript-select-nested-class-element/25487543)

And the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector)

Comment: What should document be set as? With that I think I'd get an error because 'document' hasn't been defined.

Comment: With javascript document is a default identifier for the page itsself, i don't have too too much experience with Selenium but judging off of this [webpage](https://dzone.com/articles/perform-actions-using-javascript-in-python-seleniu) you should be able to use the `document.querySelector` as one of the examples provided on that pages does just that. Sorry if this doesn't work though, most of my experience is with javascript, but based on my research on this problem this solution should work. [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) on `document`

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. I tried `driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('td a b').style.color = \"red\";")` which resulted in error `selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'style' of null`

I added in the \'s because of having quotes inside of quotes.

Comment: Really? Huh, Based on my code pen and the html you provided that should have worked in this specific situation because the element conveniently has a `<b>` element after the `<a>` and nothing else in the html you provided has elements nested similar to that and from there you could have selected the [parent elements](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentelement.asp) but if that is coming up as `null` then I cant currently think of a better solution than what i provided to select that specific element, unless I'm overthinking the problem.

Comment: I know what the real problem is. Everything is inside of a frame and I'm not sure how that changes things. I've never dealt with frames before. So I assume I have to get into the frame first before I can run any code.